# Python: add column to dictionary but not map in correct order

Tags: python, dictionary

I am adding back data that is query from Flask sqlalchemy core. The column of all the data is missing. So I add it back with the code below: There are are many columns but I just simplify to a few.

```
col = ['index','Stock','Name','MACD','STOCH','RSI']
a = call.fetchall()
print a
>>>a=[(0, 'MAGNUM', 'MAGNUM BERHAD', 'SS', 'S', 'H1'),(1,'ABC','ABC BH','SS','S','H2')]. 
dicts = [dict(zip(col, d)) for d in a]
print dicts
>>>[{'MACD': 'JAC', 'RSI': 'SS', 'STOCH': 'SB', 'Name': 'H',Stock':'H'}]
```

The dicts output skip the first result, which is index 0. It went to the index 1. Also, index was not map into the dicts.
How to make it mapping everything in correct order?

Comment: dictionary can't keep order.

Comment: do you mean `[dict(a,b) for a,b in zip(col,d)]`?

Comment: You *can* actually just do `data = [dict(row) for row in a]`, but why even do that? You can just pass `a` around and do things like `row.Stock`.

Comment: @WayneWerner, could you explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pre-suppose of the order in a dictionary.

Since you changed your question, I changed my answer. The `a` is a list of tuples so the following would work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
col = ['index','Stock','Name','MACD','STOCH','RSI']
a=[(0, 'MAGNUM', 'MAGNUM BERHAD', 'SS', 'S', 'H1'),(1,'ABC','ABC BH','SS','S','H2')]

d = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in a]

print (d)
```

It creates a list comprehension containing `OrderedDict` elements built by zipping the `col` list with each element of the `a` list of tuples.

result:

```
[OrderedDict([('index', 0), ('Stock', 'MAGNUM'), ('Name', 'MAGNUM BERHAD'), ('MACD', 'SS'), ('STOCH', 'S'), ('RSI', 'H1')]), OrderedDict([('index', 1), ('Stock', 'ABC'), ('Name', 'ABC BH'), ('MACD', 'SS'), ('STOCH', 'S'), ('RSI', 'H2')])]
```

Comment: It does not work. `a=[(0, 'MAGNUM', 'MAGNUM BERHAD', 'SS', 'S', 'H1'),(1,'ABC','ABC BH','SS','S','H2')]`. Sorry for confusion. The output I got is `OrderedDict([('index', 0,'MAGNUM','MAGNUM BERHARD','SS'), ('Stock', 'ABC','ABC BH','SS')])`

Comment: ok you changed the data afterwards. Now your code makes sense. See my updated answer. Doesn't change much.

Comment: @DanielLee the question has changed. Maybe it's time for you to undelete your post since now it answers the question :)